# Usage of SELECT NONEMPTY

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have noticed that the default for grabbing a column/row in MDX (generated from Excel) is:

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY { 
        ...
    } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { 
        ...
    } ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
```

Why is this the default behavior? When would empty columns or rows come up in actual usage?

Also, it says [`NONEMPTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/nonempty-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) is the correct name in the docs, but when I use that I get a syntax error. What's the difference between `NONEMPTY` and `NON EMPTY` -- is one deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found in documentation Nonempty is the function so it will need brackets around set expression: NONEMPTY(set_expression). NON EMPTY is the keyword.

> The big difference between the NON EMPTY keyword and the NONEMPTY
> function is when the evaluation occurs in the MDX. The NON EMPTY
> keyword is the last thing that is evaluated, in other words after all
> axes have been evaluated then the NON EMPTY keyword is executed to
> remove any empty space from the final result set. The NONEMPTY
> function is evaluated when the specific axis is evaluated.